# Will Ubuntu work well with my HP Pavilion G7 computer?

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, system-installation

I have a HP Pavilion G7 and was wondering what exactly I should look for before installing Ubuntu (as dual-boot) on it.

Will Ubuntu work okay out-of-the-box? If not, what preparations/changes do I need to make?

I'm doing my own research on this topic; I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Many, many different versions of the G7. Please include the full model number, or better yet, the result of running lspci from a *buntu LiveCD, LiveDVD or LiveUSB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to find out first if there is a stable driver for your graphic card, also make sure there is a stable driver for your WLAN card, those two issues are usually the ones that irritate new users